# Removing duplicate records after query and before returning data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm fairly new to Rails and have been familiarizing myself with the generators, but this is the first time I'm trying to create a custom route.

I have a star schema with the three tables **Clients**, **Products**, and **Features** that each have an n/n relationship to each other, so my "star" junction table has the three foreign keys, **client_id**, **product_id**, and **feature_id**. I created an API that'll return a list of clients, which each have a nested list of products, which each have a nested list of features. Here's the method that builds and returns the result:

```
def return_all
  allData = Client
                .includes(:products)
                .includes(:features)
                .to_json(:include => {:products => {:include => :features}})
  render json: allData
end
```

The issue with this is that there are multiple features for every product, so the resulting JSON returns this (I removed all but one client and some of the data for brevity sake):

```
{
"id": 13,
"name": "client_1",
"created_at": "2015-10-09T18:44:56.000Z",
"updated_at": "2015-10-09T18:44:56.000Z",
"products": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "product_1",
        "created_at": "2015-10-12T03:10:34.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2015-10-12T03:10:34.000Z",
        "features": [
            {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "email",
                "created_at": "2015-10-12T03:10:55.000Z",
                "updated_at": "2015-10-12T03:10:55.000Z",
                "value": null,
                "group": "channel"
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "name": "sms",
                "created_at": "2015-10-12T03:10:55.000Z",
                "updated_at": "2015-10-12T03:10:55.000Z",
                "value": null,
                "group": "channel"
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "ivr",
                "created_at": "2015-10-12T03:10:55.000Z",
                "updated_at": "2015-10-12T03:10:55.000Z",
                "value": null,
                "group": "channel"
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "name": "print",
                "created_at": "2015-10-12T03:10:55.000Z",
                "updated_at": "2015-10-12T03:10:55.000Z",
                "value": null,
                "group": "channel"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "product_1",
        "created_at": "2015-10-12T03:10:34.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2015-10-12T03:10:34.000Z",
        "features": [
            {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "email",
                "created_at": "2015-10-12T03:10:55.000Z",
                "updated_at": "2015-10-12T03:10:55.000Z",
                "value": null,
                "group": "channel"
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "name": "sms",
                "created_at": "2015-10-12T03:10:55.000Z",
                "updated_at": "2015-10-12T03:10:55.000Z",
                "value": null,
                "group": "channel"
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "ivr",
                "created_at": "2015-10-12T03:10:55.000Z",
                "updated_at": "2015-10-12T03:10:55.000Z",
                "value": null,
                "group": "channel"
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "name": "print",
                "created_at": "2015-10-12T03:10:55.000Z",
                "updated_at": "2015-10-12T03:10:55.000Z",
                "value": null,
                "group": "channel"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

How do I go about removing the duplicate listings of products? Please let me know if you need any more information about my question.

Thanks

Edit: by request, here are my models:

```
class ClientsFeaturesProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :feature
  belongs_to :product
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients_features_products
  has_many :features, through: :clients_features_products
  has_many :products, through: :clients_features_products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients_features_products
  has_many :clients, through: :clients_features_products
  has_many :features, through: :clients_features_products
end

class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients_features_products
  has_many :clients, through: :clients_features_products
  has_many :products, through: :clients_features_products
end
```

Comment: Please include your model code ( `has_many` and `belongs_to` associations)

Comment: Added! I pasted them all together but they're each obviously in their own model file.

Comment: try using `has_many :products, -> { distinct }, through: :clients_features_products` on the `Client` model - see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#distinct for more info

Comment: @house9 - that did it! Thank you so much for the help and reference. Post this as a solution so I can +1 it!

Comment: I have added an answer with above details, plus a few other random bits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using

```
has_many :products, -> { distinct }, through: :clients_features_products
```

on the `Client` model

see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#distinct

---

A couple of other things

- code style: use `all_data` instead of `allData`. See the style guide for more info: https://github.com/styleguide/ruby
- you might want to use `preload` instead of `includes`; includes will either act like preload or like joins and you don't know which, so I tend to stay away from it; good article here: http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/

Comment: Thank you so much! RubyMine already yelled at me about allData and I changed it to all_data. I'll also look at replacing the includes with preload.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this, but it's just a guess.

```
def return_all
  allData = Client
                .joins(:products) # might need to use raw sql
                .joins(:features)
                .to_json(:include => {:products => {:include => :features}})
  render json: allData
end
```

Alternatively, you could use [Active Model Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) to explicitly define a json view.